# DDA algorithm not drawings lines for some coordinates?

Tags: c, algorithm, bgi, line-drawing, dda

My code is working properly for slope=1 but not for other slopes. Its drawing either horizontal or vertical line for slopes other than 1. What is wrong with this code.Any help will be appreciated.

```
#include <graphics.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main( )
{
int x,y,x1,y1,x2,y2,dx,dy;
float step;

int i,gd,gm;

printf("Enter the value of x1,y1: ");
scanf("%f%f",&x1,&y1);
printf("Enter the value of x2,y2 : ");
scanf("%f%f",&x2,&y2);


detectgraph(&gd,&gm);
initgraph(&gd,&gm,"");

dx=abs(x2-x1);
dy=abs(y2-y1);

if(dx>=dy)
step=dx;
else
step=dy;

dx=dx/step;
dy=dy/step;

x=x1;
y=y1;

i=1;
while(i<=step)
{
      putpixel(x,y,1);
      x=x+dx;
      y=y+dy;
      i=i+1;
      delay(100);
}
getch();
}
```

Comment: http://scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-lessons/lesson-12-acceleration-structures/grid/ for some information and code on the DDA algorithm in general.

Answer (score 2):

```
dx=dx/step;
dy=dy/step;
```

You've made step a float, but dx and dy are integer.  As such, this divide is going to give you a 0 in one of these 2 values.  I was under the impression that DDA routines were all integer so having the float in there at all makes me wonder.  I'll look deeper at the algorithm and see what else I find.

[Here's](http://labprograms.wordpress.com/2010/02/08/dda-line-drawing-algorithm-using-c/) a routine that uses floats in a way that won't zero the step.

and [another](http://www.programming-techniques.com/2012/01/drawing-straight-line-using-dda.html) for windows.

Comment: after correcting dx,dy to float its working for some but there is a problem for eg. if am taking (200,0) and (0,200) the line drawn is not right.

Comment: You need to special case horizontal/vertical lines to prevent a divide by 0.  Look at various samples on the internet for guidance here.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are just accepting one value in the

```
scanf("%f%f",&x1);
scanf("%f%f",&y1);
```

statements. Try correcting that and running the code once again.

Comment: oh sorry..its typing mistake. i have written correctly in actual code.